# Using java language to calculate the value of an expression(or equation) dynamically

Tags: java, equation-solving, arithmetic-expressions

I have to write a method that accepts three arguments and an arithmetic expression(or equation).Based on the equation the result has to be returned.But the problem is that the equation is given as a string that has to be converted to do the arithmetic (I am confused how to do it).How we can solve this problem effectively in java.The code for the same is given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getResult(2,3,5,"(a+b)*c/(a+c)"));
}
static double getResult(int a,int b,int c,String expr)
{
    //double result=(a+b)*c/(a+c);
    double result=expr;
    return result;
}
```

Here the getResult method has to accept three integers and the equation as a string.It would be great if someone can suggest the solution or an alternative way to effectively solve this problem.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.Rewritten code that makes use of Javaluator library.

```
    StaticVariableSet<Double> variablelist = new StaticVariableSet<Double>();
    variablelist.set("a", 2.0);
    variablelist.set("b", 3.0);
    variablelist.set("c", 5.0);

    System.out.println(new DoubleEvaluator().evaluate("(a+b)*c/(a+c)",variablelist));
```

Comment: What are your limitations, in terms of "allowed to do X" and "supposed do to Y"? You can imagine that this has been solved before many, many times. If you need to do this as a professional, you would just grab one of the many libraries.

Comment: @tucuxi Thanks anyways my problem is solved.Can use some java expression evaluator library

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string into a valid expression and then find the value. Have a look at recursive descent parser to start with. You can use 3rd party librares (if you are allowed to do so)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Is it  the easiest solution.Is there any helping libraries to do it in the language itself.

Comment: Look at this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Thanks.Can use some java expression evaluator library